# Setting codeigniter custom route

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I am trying to set a custom route for friendly url when loading a tag, by that I mean that I want to convert this: `http://test.com/en/results?search_query=data&search=tag` to this `http://test.com/en/tag/data`

Tried to do so by setting this in my routes.php:

`$route['^(en|es|ro)/tag/(:any)']   = "fetch/results?search_query=$1&search=tag";`

But no success, am I doing it wrong?

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";

// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/(.+)$']  = "video/id/$2";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/results$']     = "fetch/results$2";
$route['(en|es|ro)/tag/(:any)']   = "fetch/results?search_query=$2&search=tag";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/(.+)$']        = "$2";

// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|es|ro)$'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['404_override']  = '';
```

Comment: the ^ forces the match at the start of the string, but i don't see that pattern in the question anywhere, the /en/ part occurs in the middle.

Comment: it's `en/`, and the way it works it that `en` is the match at the start of the string. That's how the library works. That's not the problem, but tnx anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the `^` is not necessary. Try without it:

```
$route['(en|es|ro)/tag/(:any)'] = "fetch/results?search_query=$1&search=tag";
```

In that context, `^` will be treated as a literal string. If you wanted top use a regex, I believe you'd have to wrap the regex itself in parentheses, like so:

```
$route['(^(en|es|ro))/tag/(:any)'] = "fetch/results?search_query=$1&search=tag";
```

I'm not 100% certain on that, but if I'm correct both should work. However, routes always assume the first part of the pattern is what the string should start with, so the `^` shouldn't be necessary anyways.

**One more thing**: You aren't using the second match, but the first. I believe you want to replace `$1` with `$2` in your route.

```
$route['(en|es|ro)/tag/(:any)'] = "fetch/results?search_query=$2&search=tag";
//       ^^^1^^^^      ^^^2^^                                 ^^
```

---

**EDIT**: Upon further investigation and testing, it seems that Codeigniter cannot properly handle routes that use a query string like `?key=value`. If you use a slash before the `?` question mark, you can at least get it to route to the right controller and method:

```
$route['(en|es|ro)/tag/(:any)'] = "fetch/results/?search_query=$2&search=tag";
```

A url like this:

> `http://example.com/es/tag/Codeigniter's Router`

...will be routed to the `results` method with this string as an argument, but `$_GET` will be empty:

> `?search_query=Codeigniter%27s%20Router&search=tag`

So, you could pick apart the argument with [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
function results($request)
{
    $request = ltrim($request, '?');
    parse_str($request, $get);
    // echo $get['search_query']
}
```

You could always use `.htaccess` of course, but I understand the desire to keep all the routing logic in one place. Sorry if this isn't the answer you hoped for, but I'm afraid that without writing a custom router it's not possible to do this the obvious way in Codeigniter. My suggestion would probably be to find another way to handle your routing and the way you're accessing data from the URL.

Comment: tnx for the info and the proposed solution Madmartigan, I will try it tomorrow... right now is time to sleep. :)

Comment: it ain't working, don't know why... I can't really understand why not. Check the edit

Comment: Tell me if this one works as a test: `$route['(en|es|ro)/(:any)'] = "fetch/results/$1/$2";` Use a url like `/en/something` and in the `fetch` controller, do a `print_r($this->uri->rsegment->array())`

Comment: it's that in fetch.php the requests run with `$this->input->get()` and I don't use segment for nothing. Ex `$action = ($this->input->get('search') == NULL) ? 'search' : $this->input->get('search', TRUE);`

Comment: Yes I know, I'm asking you to do this as a test so we can narrow down the cause of the problem. Is `fetch.php` a controller?

Comment: Array(
    [1] => fetch
    [2] => results
    [3] => es
    [4] => alex
)

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much for the info... but I am going to keep it the old way for now and maybe in the future I will change it

Comment: I'm trying to do it using `.htaccess` just to test to see if it works ok... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to escape the forwardslashes around tag. So it should look like this:

```
$route['^(en|es|ro)\/tag\/(:any)']
```

Comment: No need to escape the forward slash, it's kind of a perverted regex they use, the pattern isn't just passed in as-is. And I know I'm nitpicking, but those aren't backslashes you're escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, and it looks like

```
$route['(:any)/something/(:any)'] = "real/$2/path/$1";
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to limit the first segment to `en`, `es`, or `ro`, otherwise - do not route the request.